# OSError: Unable to open file (File signature not found) in ec2 instance

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-ec2, deep-learning, tf.keras, git-lfs

I have trained a lstm model from which I could able to make predictions using model.h5 file (used model.save(model.save(/path/)) to save model). But the same code when deployed in ec2 instance while reading the model.h5 using keras load_model method

```
model.save('artifacts/model_trainer/model.h5')

loaded_model=load_model('artifacts/model_trainer/model.h5')
loaded_model.predict(inputs)
```

I am getting this error. The model.h5 file is around 104 mb so I used github lfs to push it to github.
I suspect this might be the issue. If anyone has any lead please feel free to answer.

Tried in the local it is working fine.
Expectation: The application should work as expected in aws ec2 instance also.